# How to find all documents with specific field in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have many different documents in ES cluster, and I wonder how to find all documents that contain field `num-users`?

Comment: Hm, I have no idea what you are trying to ask. Can you re-phrase the question of offer more details?

Comment: Not all my documents content field "num-users". I want to:

Comment: I want to know how i can find all documents with

Comment: this field. How can I request this documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [exists filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-filter.html) to find out documents having that field

Comment: @Smasell This answer only links to a website which can disappear one day. The answer by Phonolog is much better because it provides a direct solution including code sample. In my opinion that answer should be selected as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Updating Prabins answer:

The exists filter has been replaced by the [exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html). You can use it like this:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "exists" : { "field" : "num-users" }
    }
}
```